# UK Mortgage security law

Tags: england-and-wales, mortgage

Do any laws of England stop banks from blocking second mortgages by securing excessive values on a mortgage ?

I have a New Zealand mortgage where my bank blocks second mortgages by securing $520,000 on a $350,000 mortgage. I know English banks don't do this, but is it encoded in law ?

Comment: There would be no need; they can just not consent to you taking out a second mortgage.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your question. Are you asking if one is entitled by law to a 2nd mortgage regardless of the bank declining to give one due to their policies and/or economic business model? Or are you asking if the law expressly prohibits excessive 2nd mortgages?

Comment: It is an Australian bank (probably criminals). They wrote on the mortgage security they can claim $520,000 which makes the second mortgage very risky. I only owe $350,000. I've complained to my MP, and they asked about the specific UK law that stops UK banks doing this.